# highcharts export png files

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I have a problem with the highcharts export server.

I Try to paint a graphic format. Png and jumps me the following error.

Timeout converting SVG,is your file this big, or maybe you have a syntax error in the javascript callback?
anyone knows how to increase the timeout call? if I make less expensive representations paints them without problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open highcharts-convert.js file. There you have:

```
var config = {
        /* define locations of mandatory javascript files */
        HIGHCHARTS: 'highstock.js',
        HIGHCHARTS_MORE: 'highcharts-more.js',
        HIGHCHARTS_DATA: 'data.js',
        JQUERY: 'jquery.1.9.1.min.js',
        TIMEOUT: 2000 /* 2 seconds timout for loading images */
    },
```

As you can see, there is timeout, set it higher and should work fine. For course that solution is suppose to work for phantomJS server.

Comment: does that over-ride was is in app-convert.properties?

Comment: Nope, only changes timeout for phantomJS.

Comment: @PawełFus what is HighCharts_data : data.js for?

Comment: It's Highcharts data module, see [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module).